# Build IOS in flutter it's showing GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m Plugin headers not found ex :(#import <firebase_analytics/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.h>)

Tags: ios, flutter

```
//  Generated file. Do not edit.

#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
#import <firebase_analytics/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.h>
#import <firebase_auth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.h>
#import <firebase_core/FirebaseCorePlugin.h>
#import <firebase_storage/FirebaseStoragePlugin.h>
#import <flutter_facebook_login/FacebookLoginPlugin.h>
#import <google_sign_in/GoogleSignInPlugin.h>
#import <image_picker/ImagePickerPlugin.h>
#import <path_provider/PathProviderPlugin.h>
#import <shared_preferences/SharedPreferencesPlugin.h>

@implementation GeneratedPluginRegistrant

+ (void)registerWithRegistry:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistry>*)registry {
  [FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin"]];
  [FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin"]];
  [FLTFirebaseCorePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseCorePlugin"]];
  [FLTFirebaseStoragePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseStoragePlugin"]];
  [FacebookLoginPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FacebookLoginPlugin"]];
  [FLTGoogleSignInPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTGoogleSignInPlugin"]];
  [FLTImagePickerPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTImagePickerPlugin"]];
  [FLTPathProviderPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTPathProviderPlugin"]];
  [FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin"]];
}

@end
```

"   Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
    Running pod install...
    Running Xcode build...
    Xcode build done.                                            9.6s
    Failed to build iOS app
    Error output from Xcode build:
    ↳
        ** BUILD FAILED **

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/******/Documents/****/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: fatal error: 'firebase_analytics/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.h' file not found
    #import <firebase_analytics/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone XR."
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33423#issue-449171891

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using `firebase_analytics: 6.0.0` and I didn't encounter any issues during my build on iOS. I've checked the [GitHub thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33423#issuecomment-503137624) you've shared and it looks like the issue has been solved by updating the plugin version. Another solution posted was to regenerate the pods by running `flutter clean` and running a build.

For other folks that still have this issue after doing the steps above, you can run `flutter doctor -v` to check for any errors and warnings and file an Issue here https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues